# AWS Cloudwatch Log - Add variable in log_stream_name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using the AWS Cloudwatch Log agent. It works good, fine.
I have a config like that :

```
[type1]
datetime_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
file = /var/log/payment_type1.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = payment
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = type1

[type2]
datetime_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
file = /var/log/payment_type2.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = payment
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = type2
```

I have one section per payment mode. Is it possible to group all these section in one ? And add a variable in the log_group_name tag.
Something like that for example ?

```
[type]
datetime_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
file = /var/log/payment_(<my_type>.*).log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = payment
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = my_type
```

Thanks for your help.

Eric